# PostMessage() or such on OS X. Sending messages to a window

Tags: macos, postmessage, window-messages

What is the equivalent of PostMessage/SendMessage in Windows on Mac OS X?

I have recently started out with Mac development, with most of my experience coming from Windows and nix.

I want to hook a window and simulate mouse clicks or keyboard presses. Also I want to be able to find a function like GetWindowText or any function that can get a certain text from a window.

Comment: Does the window belong to your app?

Comment: I should have mentioned that. No it does not.

Answer (score 0):

One can send low-level events using Quartz event APIs such as `CGEventPostToPSN`.  To get text from another app's window, I think your best bet would be the Accessibility APIs (just type "accessibility" in the Xcode search box), though I have no personal experience with that.

Comment: Can I simulate a button click on a certain object in a window with CGEventPostToPSN? It's a UIButton that I want to press.

Comment: You asked about Mac OS X, but UIButton is from iOS.  It looks like CGEventPostToPSN doesn't exist in iOS.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was called UIButton in OS X as well. Well OS X is my platform.

Comment: OK, that would be NSButton.  If you know its location, you could post a click event there.

Comment: I still have no idea how to get a certain memory-segment of text from the external window. Accessibility has gotten me nowhere. I bump this in hope of getting a reply that may push me in the right direction. Also worth mentioning, I tried UIBrowser (http://pfiddlesoft.com/uibrowser/) but I could not find the specific text I was looking for with help from UIBrowser.

Comment: Is the specific text you're looking for part of a standard control or field?  If it's just drawn on the window using low-level graphics APIs, then it wouldn't be accessible unless the app takes special steps to make it so.